# MvvmCross custom log provider not logging from itself

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm trying to implement an UDP-LogProvider. For LogMessages which I write myself it does work. But I am missing messages from Mvvmcross itself like failure message on wrong binding ect. In the past with `ImvxTrace` that worked like a charm.

LogProvider:

```
public class UdpLogProvider : IMvxLogProvider
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IMvxLog> _logs = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IMvxLog>();

    public IMvxLog GetLogFor<T>()
    {
        return GetLogFor(typeof(T).Name);
    }

    public IMvxLog GetLogFor(string name)
    {
        if (_logs.TryGetValue(name, out var log))
        {
            return log;
        }

        log = new DebugTrace(name);
        _logs.AddOrUpdate(name, log, (s, l) => log);

        return log;
    }

    public IDisposable OpenNestedContext(string message)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IDisposable OpenMappedContext(string key, string value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Setup.cs:

```
protected override IMvxLogProvider CreateLogProvider()
{           
    return new UdpLogProvider();
}
```

When I debug my LogProvider I can see that MvxSetup and MvxLog is requesting an LogInstance but no message is ever sent to this instances. Am I missing something?

Thx in advance

Comment: Internally we still use IMvxTrace for logging. In 6.0 this will be replaced with the new IMvxLog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx goes to Martijn00 who gave the answer. Mvvmcross still uses IMvxTrace internally. This will be replaced in version 6.0. That means that the logger should implement IMvxTrace and IMvxLog.